# How to implement my own collection that can be used like a dictionary

Tags: .net, vb.net

So I have an object that is part of a reply from a web request that has two properties on it. Both are string arrays. The first one is called COLUMNNAMES and the second is called VALUES. For instance COLUMNNAMES would have the following in it:

"ID", "NAME", "DATEADDED", "DATECHANGED"

and VALUES would have the following in it:

"1", "APPLES", "09/21/2013", "09/21/2013"

"2", "ORANGES", "09/21/2013", "09/21/2013"

"3", "STRAWBERRIES", "09/21/2013", "09/21/2013"

What I want to be able to do is somehow process these into a sort of data structure that I can call like so:

```
Dim rows = GetReply()

For Each r in rows
    Dim value = r("ID") 'ID is a column name
Next
```

Is there a type that I can implement to create this or does this already exist? Thanks!

Comment: The DataTable class was made for this.

Comment: I use data tables every day and didn't even think about them. Too early in the morning for me! Thanks!

Comment: If you answered your own question either make your own answer and mark it accepted or delete the question so it does not keep popping up to the front page as a question with no accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best answer here was a datatable.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use LINQ to munge this into a sequence of `Dictionary`s:

```
class Reply {
    string[] _columnNames = {"ID", "NAME"}; // the list of columns you received

    string[][] _rowValues = { // the lists of values you received
        new[]{"1", "APPLES"},
        new[]{"2", "ORANGE"}
    };

    public IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, string>> Rows {
        get {
            foreach (var row in _rowValues) {
                yield return _columnNames
                                .Zip(row, (key, value) => new {key, value})
                                .ToDictionary(kv=>kv.key, kv=>kv.value);
            }
        }
    }
}

// ...

foreach (row in new Reply().Rows) {
    var id = row["ID"];
    var name = row["NAME"];
}
```